# System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer Sharepoint Online event receiver solution not working

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Running into an extremely weird issue where JavaScriptSerializer makes an event receiver solution fail in Sharepoint Online. The weird part is that it fails silently and it doesn't throw an exception.
However inside of a web-part JavaScriptSerializer works just fine
Has anyone else run into this before ?

Comment: anyone have any clue about this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check suggestions from the [Using System.Web.Extensions in Crm plugin](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ce3c4e6-0587-4913-89f8-f3942d7bac93/using-systemwebextensions-in-crm-plugin) thread.

If your issue is different, enable the VERBOSE logging mode and share the corresponding LOG info here.

Comment: Don't think I can enable VERBOSE logging mode in Sharepoint Online